# What plant is this flowering shrub in winter?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, flowers

I thought plants go dormant in winter and don’t flower. Was happy to see this beautiful shrub or tree. Zone 8 in pacific NW. [image: near Seattle]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Camelia Japonica, very happy in zone 8, there are hundreds of varieties ,colors white to pink to red, some with spotted coloring. The flowers look small, but correct color multiple petals for "Debutante". There is a very small chance it is a Camelia susanqua with very large flowers. Japonicas will bloom from the first of December until March in zone 8 depending on variety and exact location ; I have one Debutante many blooms and another with only a few blooms remaining.

Comment: Thank you. Your yard must be beautiful

Comment: It has some good spots . Also ,iit is typical  of a japonica to drop the blooms after a couple days , but not susanqua .